# I need to send Push Notificartions to specific users desktops

Tags: notifications

I am looking to be able to send automated push notification (preferrebly with sound) from a trigger such as a webhook/api call, whether though a native browser, operating system feature or a 3rd party application.

The notification needs to be targeted to specific users, for example if "Person A" where to win a raffle then only that user would get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Through email, or a notification on the desktop?

If it is email, then you can add an `if` block of code with an email bot that will send the email if the raffle is won. If it's the desktop, I have no idea.

Comment: Through a notification on the desktop preferably.

Comment: Oh. Darn. I found a simple email bot: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/send-emails-using-code-4fcea9df63f

Comment: I'll take a look. It might end up being a easier solution.

Comment: Okay. Please don't downvote me if it is unsuccessful.